# NetworkManager not connecting to eth0 on boot

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I am trying to set up a network using the NetworkManager. The problem is that the network isn't starting automatticaly on boot.

After booting up, i try to ping the target address (192.168.43.1) and it prints: *connect: Network is unreachable*. Then i run:

```
nmcli device status
```

and my device "eth0" of type "ethernet" is "unavailable". After running:

```
nmcli connection eth0 up
```

it prints *Error: Connection activation failed. Active connection could not be attached to the device*.

Then i run it again and it works: *Connection successfully activated*... And then i ping the target address again and it works.

Why isn't the connection staring up automatically? "manage" is set false at the NetworkManager conf, so it doesn't use the configuration from intarfaces. I have looked around for some help, but couldnt solve the problem. Here some helpfull information:

eth0 configuration as static in: [/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzilA.png)

as you can see, no configuration of eth0 in: [/etc/network/interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlLft.png)

Configuration of: [/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xOf0.png)

Log failing to connect: [journalctl -u NetworkManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz88q.png)

After boot up (not working) [sudo lshw -C network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyrm4.png)

After "nmcli connection up eth0" [sudo lshw -C network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNHC8.png)

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Added "sudo lshw -C network" output bevore and after the connection works.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` when it's not working, and then again when it is working. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Hello, thanks for your answer. I edited my question with both screenshots as requested. The only change i see is that "Network 3" becomes an IP after i start the connection manualy. I expected this behavior after booting up automatically.

Comment: Please describe your network configuration, including cabling from the computer to the router/modem. Do you have a USB to ethernet adapter connected? What is can0 and can1? Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables? What is dummy0? It looks like you have a cabling problem, or a 1G hub/switch/router that's misbehaving.

Comment: @heynnema Hi again. I am using a Jetson TX2 from Nvidia connected to a RaspberryPI over a CAT5 cable. I added the line "nmcli connection up eth0" to /etc/rc.local and it works now. But i guess it isnt the solution for this problem. It is just a work around. Another problem that i have is that if i remove the ethernet cable for a few seconds, a connection eth0:avahi is created. If i insert the cable again, it wont change back to eth0 and i have again to restart the connection with "nmcli connection down eth0" and "nmcli connection up eth0".

Comment: You didn't answer all of my questions. So, is the connectivity problem on the TX2, or the Pi? Which device is connected to the network? Do you have a cat 5e or cat 6 cable? Both of your lshw commands indicate a possible cable problem.